# Populate slice of objects together with referenced objects

Tags: go, go-gorm

Imagine I have 2 structs:

```
type Order struct {
     ID             int64 `gorm:"primary_key"`
     CurrentStateID int64 
     CurrentState   *OrderState
}
type OrderState struct {
   ID      int64
   .... // other fields
}
```

Now I want to make a search given a slice of `orderIDs` and have a slice of `Order` with filled `CurrentState` fields.

My current solution is really ugly as I firstly fetch all orders without states, then arrange state ids into a slice and make a search by them. After that, I iterate in a for loop over orders and match orders and states together. Like

```
var (
    states []*State
    orders []*Orders
)
//searches are done here
for _, order := range orders {
    for _, state := range states {
        if order.CurrentStateID == state.ID {
             order.CurrentState = state 
             break
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to eagerly load the CurrentState when fetching your Orders.

In this case, I would suggest taking a look at the Preload-API at http://jinzhu.me/gorm/crud.html#preloading-eager-loading